# Coloring and animating an array in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to build a basic version of Conway's game of life in Python. I've made an array of 0s as a blank background, with 1s replacing the points to be colored. However, I can't assign colors to 0 and 1 and simultaneously animate the plot.
Here's the complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np 

grid = np.zeros((11,11), dtype=np.int16)

def neighbors(x,y):
    n_cells = [grid[x-1, y+1], grid[x, y+1], grid[x+1, y+1], 
                grid[x-1, y], grid[x+1, y], 
                grid[x-1, y-1], grid[x, y-1], grid[x+1, y-1]]
    return sum(n_cells)

grid[3:6,5]=1

newgrid = grid.copy()
def updatefig(i):
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            if grid[x,y]==0:
                if neighbors(x,y)==3:
                    newgrid[x,y]=1
            else:
                if neighbors(x,y)<2 or neighbors(x,y)>3:
                    newgrid[x,y]=0
    return newgrid

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels([])  
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
    
plt.imshow(grid, cmap='binary') 
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

If I use cmap in plt.imshow(), I have to give an argument, which leads to a static plot and no animation. If I don't assign colors and just run the animation, I get a white screen. I've looked for solutions and tried them, but haven't had any luck.

If I can just assign colors to 0 and 1 without imshow, I think it'll work out. Any ideas?

Edit: I realised my loop is flawed and it only gives 1 updated array. I'm trying to resolve that issue, but animation is still required regardless.

Comment: What is the `fig` param?

Comment: Sorry? I'm new to this, but if you're asking about the `fig, ax` statement, I have only used it later in the code for removing axis labels and ticks.

Comment: You said this is the complete code, and yet you have: `ani = FuncAnimation(fig ... `. What is the `fig` param?

Comment: Apologies, I've added it now.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, will post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, it wasn't a problem with the `plt.imshow()` and animation simultaneously, it was my loop itself that was the problem. Once it was fixed, it worked.
Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np 

grid = np.zeros((11,11), dtype=np.int16) 

def neighbors(x,y):
    #cell = grid[x,y]
    n_cells = [grid[x-1, y+1], grid[x, y+1], grid[x+1, y+1], 
                grid[x-1, y], grid[x+1, y], 
                grid[x-1, y-1], grid[x, y-1], grid[x+1, y-1]]
    return sum(n_cells)

grid[3:6,5]=1

newgrid = grid.copy()
def updatefig(i):
    for x in range(10):
        for y in range(10):
            if grid[x,y]==0:
                if neighbors(x,y)==3:
                    newgrid[x,y]=1
            else:
                if neighbors(x,y)<2 or neighbors(x,y)>3:
                    newgrid[x,y]=0

    def update_grid():
        global grid
        grid = newgrid.copy()

    update_grid()

    plt.imshow(newgrid, cmap='binary')
    

ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels([])  
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])

#plt.imshow(grid, cmap='binary') 

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, interval=100)
plt.show()
```

I've used `imshow` inside the loop, but it works even if I uncomment the one above the animation function.